# g:render tag renders body() as plain text

Tags: templates, grails, gsp

I'm trying to render the template in GSP page

template:

```
<div class="container">
  ${body()}
</div>
```

template call:

```
<g:render template="/shared/wrapperTemplate">
  <g:textField name="${property}" value="${value}" id="${property}id" class="form-control"/>
</g:render>
```

The body() is evaluated correctly and renders

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="nameid" class="form-control" />
```

but when passing it to the template, it is surrounded by the quotes and instead of displaying input field, it prints the html input as string to the html page

I also tried with write TagLib

```
def fieldTemplate = { attrs, body ->
    out << render(template: "/shared/wrapperTemplate",  model: [content: body()])
}
```

But the result was the same (of course I had to change the tag call)

The idea was to reuse the formatting part of the template `<div>` for all _wrapper.gsp templates in Fields plugin, but not copy paste it. The case above is simplified, but I use Twitter Bootstrap and there is a bunch of lines that I don't want to copy.

_fields/default/_wrapper.gsp:

```
<div class="form-group ${hasErrors(bean:bean,field:property,'has-error')}">
  <label for="${property}id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">${label}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <g:textField name="${property}" value="${value}" id="${property}id" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

_fields/date/_wrapper.gsp:

```
<div class="form-group ${hasErrors(bean:bean,field:property,'has-error')}">
<label for="${property}id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">${label}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <g:datePicker name="${property}" value="${value}" precision="day" id="${property}id" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you want to do or render? As far as I know, the `g:render` tag doesn't have content. The `template` attribute refers to the `gsp` file and its content that is to be rendered (in your case that would probably be "shared/wrapperTemplate").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to understand the following lines of your post

> but when passing **it** to the template, it is surrounded by the quotes
>   and instead of displaying input field, it prints the html input as
>   string to the html page

What is **it** in this case, please share the exact code which is not working.
The first example you shared is working for you, in the second example you passed content as parameter. When you are passing the parament then you need to change your code from

```
${body()}
```

to

```
${raw(content)}
```

I am still not sure what is the exact code which not working, just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works just perfect.
Template (cannot format comment):
`<div class="form-group ${hasErrors(bean:bean,field:property,'has-error')}">
    <label for="${property}id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">${label}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        ${raw(body())}
    </div>
</div>`